# Correct way to start multiple TweetStream daemons for monitoring Twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, daemon

I'm using Tweetstream gem to monitor a single twitter userstream and am looking to extend this to monitoring a userstream for each user of the site.  I am currently starting this daemon through a rake on deployment.  Introducing multiple daemons (one for each user) introduces some issues I haven't dealt with before:

1. How do I start all these daemons?  I will start one for a user when he signs up.  Would it make sense to additionally stop them all on Capistrano deploy then run rake task that loops through all my users and starts a daemon for each again?
2. How do I monitor all the daemons to make sure they are all correctly functioning?
3. What is going to be the cost in terms of RAM and processing of having lots of daemons running?
4. Are there any other considerations I'm missing.

Your insights will give me the confidence to proceed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that they actually do not want this currently as of (Jan 11th, 2012).  From their documentation:

> User Streams  Nearly all data required to update a user's display.
>   Requires the user's OAuth token. Provides public and protected
>   statuses from followings, direct messages, mentions, and other events
>   taken on and by the user. A large number of User Streams may not be
>   created from the same host or service. For example, an application
>   that displays a few accounts at once may open a connection per
>   account. The primary use case is providing updates to a Twitter
>   client.
>
> Site Streams  BETA Allows multiplexing of multiple User Streams over a
>   Site Stream connection. Once more than a handful of User Streams
>   connections are opened from the same host or service, Site Streams
>   must be used. The primary use case is website and other service
>   integrations.

So it seems i should apply for access to this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code obviously, but tweetstream can monitor multiple users with one daemon.  This code is from [their docs](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream):

```
# Use 'follow' to follow a group of user ids (integers, not screen names)
TweetStream::Client.new.follow(14252, 53235) do |status|
  puts "#{status.text}"
end
```

This just uses the Twitter API 'follow' parameter which is described in [Twitter's API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#follow). Obviously you will need to process the incoming data and do whatever it is you are doing, but each [status element](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3aid) should return the data you need to parse out your users. Unless your app is very small, running multiple processes to do this work is really not a good option.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've added an answer showing Twitter's official stance.  The idea of following is something I considered but that shows in some cases a limited view of a users stream and therefore did not meet our requirements.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question, I thought you wanted to track their tweets.